# Classes and Constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Person {
public:
    int age;
    Person(int initialAge);
    void amIOld();
    void yearPasses();
};

Person::Person(int initialAge)
{
    if (initialAge > 0) {
        initialAge = age;
    }
    else if (initialAge < 0) {
        cout << "Age is not valid, setting age to 0. \n";
        age = 0;
    }

    // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
}

void Person::amIOld()
{

    if (age < 13) {
        cout << "You are young. \n";
    }
    else if (age >= 13 && age <= 18) {
        cout << "You are a teenager. \n";
    }
    else if (age > 18) {
        cout << "You are old. \n";
    }
    // Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console
}

void Person::yearPasses()
{
    age = age + 1;
    // Increment the age of the person in here
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    int age;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> age;
        Person p(age);
        p.amIOld();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            p.yearPasses();
        }
        p.amIOld();

        cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

input 4 -1 10 16 18

output expected:

Age is not valid, setting age to 0.
You are young.
You are young.

You are young.
You are a teenager.

You are a teenager.
You are old.

You are old.
You are old.

output I am getting is:

Age is not valid, setting age to 0.
You are young.
You are young.

You are young.
You are young.

You are young.
You are young.

You are young.
You are young.

Comment: `initialAge=age;` - what is wrong with this line?

Comment: and when `initialAge == 0` you do not initialize the member

Comment: Why do I get output as "You are young." no matter what age I provide?

Comment: @SakshiMishra Do you understand the difference between `initialAge=age;` and `age=initialAge;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Constructor function of class change

```
initialAge = age;
```

to

```
age = initialAge;
```

because you have to set value of initialAge to age

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in constructor.
Use initializer list to avoid such issues.
something like

```
Person::Person(int initialAge):age(initialAge > 0 ? initialAge : 0)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some logical mistakes in your code.

The first one is in your constructor, you should set `age = initialAge` you did it the other way around.

The second one is if you want it to say "You are old" when the age is 18, you should change your last else clause to be `else if(age >= 18)` and change the second if clause to `else if(age >= 13 && age < 18)`. Otherwise, it says you are young when you're 18.

If you are working with small classes or experimenting with them, I recommend you declare and define your methods inside your class. it makes it easier to read.

this would be a simpler version of your code that works like you intend it to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    int age;
    Person(int initialAge){
        if (initialAge >= 0) 
            age = initialAge;
        else if (initialAge < 0) {
            cout << "Age is not valid, setting age to Zero.\n";
            age = 0;
        }
    }
    void amIOld(){
        if (age < 13) 
            cout << "You are young.\n";
        else if (age >= 13 && age < 18) 
            cout << "You are a teenager.\n";
        else 
            cout << "You are old.\n";   
    }
    void yearPasses(){
        age += 1;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int t, age;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> age;
        Person p(age);
        p.amIOld();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            p.yearPasses();
        p.amIOld();
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```